# Static pointer default value in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, static

As static variable declaration without any value assigned goes in BSS section of code. where it will be automatically initialed to zero.

Question:
    suppose, if declare static pointer without any assignment, then **whether should it have zero value for address or value?**

Comment: Note, dup is only tagged C.

Comment: Looks like you are a bit confused about pointer variable and its value. Just remember, **pointer variable is a variable itself**, which means it has a value, but in this case you can use its value as an address.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C a static pointer will be initialized to null, the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.8` *Initialization* paragraph *10* says:

> an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:

and included the following bullet:

> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;

So no storage is allocated for it, it is a null pointer. Also note it is an implementation defined behavior where static variables are stored.

The relevant section for [the C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) would be section `8.5` *Initializers* paragraph *13* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [ Note: **Objects with static or thread storage duration are 
>   zero-initialized**, see 3.6.2. —end note ]

*zero-initialize* is covered in paragraph *6* which says:

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:

and has the following bullet:

> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T;<sup>103</sup>

where *footnote* `103` says (*emphasis mine*):

> As specified in 4.10, converting an integral constant expression whose value is 0 to a **pointer type results in a null pointer value**.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer will point to address zero (NULL on most systems). You will still need to point it somewhere valid (e. g. from malloc) before using it as a pointer.

Comment: No, it will be initialized to the NULL pointer value, whether or not its representation is zero. For pointers, the constant 0 transforms to the NULL pointer value, _not_ the bit pattern of all zeros.